# Creat File with Process Names with filter

Tags: linux, unix, terminal

For a UNIX class we are supposed to create a file with the name `deamons` that contains all the processes whose names end with `d`.

My approach was to use something like:

```
ps | find PID *d
```

or

```
find *d > ps
```

but none of these approaches is anywhere close to achieving the results I want.

We have used `ls`, `ps`, `find`, `grep` and some other basic UNIX commands so far. The terminal runs in CentOS 5 and we don't have rights to install any packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well ... you're using the wrong tool, `find` is for finding files. You want to use `grep`. A bare `ps` probably also isn't what you want.

```
ps -e | grep 'd$' > daemons
```

I highly recommend that you familiarise yourself with the tools at your disposal before stringing them together.

Btw, what were the outputs/results of your own invocations? ;) 
That's a good learning exercise, trying to understand what you actually did.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! After some conversation with my fellow students I was stuck after pgrep -l [*d]. So why does grep 'd$' work and [*d] doesn't? I tought '$' is for variables.

Comment: The outputs where error. Because as you said, find is for files/folder and outputed file doesn't exist.

Comment: e.g. ps -e | grep [?d], ignores the ? and moves on like ?d?

Comment: beforelinebreak$, found it in my slides but still I can't get the other expressions to work like ?,*,^. Shouldn't pgrep 'ba*$' output bash?

Comment: @Freddy, grep uses regular expressions, not shell globbing. I can't teach you this here in a discussion thread, though, that's not in scope for the site (or use of my time, really ;}).

Comment: @Freddy that's what I thougth but regular expressions and shell globbin seam like good keywords to find something via google.